# Cmd.exe no popup

Tags: command-line

I have to run cmd / c from a program, run the start command xx.exe, and I capture the result (there xx.exe?). until everything is right, however, remains open the console with the error popup. how can I close the console with the error?

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear. For example, we can't really tell what "until everything is right" means. Please specify exactly what you are trying to do, and what's happening instead.

Comment: Sorry for my english..

    cmd /c yy.exe

After this command, shows a popup error and the shell does not close
there are cmd option to end the shell ignoring the pop-up?

Answer (score 0):

Usually win32 applications will close the command prompt after execution. If this isn't the case with what you're trying to run, you could:

- Run it from Windows "Run" option (Windows button+R) than your program name and path in prompt.
- Run it from a batch file, like so:

runMe.bat:

```
START "" "C:\windows\notepad.exe"
EXIT`
```

Than just run `runMe.bat` from wherever. Notice the 'exit' command that closes the command prompt after execution.

Read more about batch files, the start command, and this issue [here](http://www.computerhope.com/starthlp.htm), and [there](https://superuser.com/questions/192550/why-wont-cmd-exit-after-execution-of-batch-file).
Good luck!